# Please don't close questions that are for "developers"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, bug-reports

I see questions on Ask Ubuntu set to on-hold or being closed because they involved bugs and are meant for "developers".

Stated in the description for askubuntu.com

> Ask Ubuntu is a question and answer site for Ubuntu users and **developers**. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Ubuntu.

Please don't close those questions, otherwise we will get the same question every time, since most users experience the same issue.

[Link to the question involved.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010008/ubuntu-18-04-beta-login-loop-after-failed-upgrade)

Comment: 18.04 is off-topic because it's the development version and development versions are not supported here. From [the on-topic questions page](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), "Questions that you should avoid:
· Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1)"

Comment: Plus, it's a bug and "Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues."

Comment: So its forbidden to report in on Launchpad AND leave the question open ?

Comment: @An0n no, there are cases where the question *can* be answered with a workaround, but this is not the case for the question you've linked to.

Comment: Shall i delete this question ? Im aware of the issue now.

Comment: @An0n You can leave the meta question here, no need to delete it.  (I thought you meant the question you linked to)

Comment: @An0n it's a built-in in the system, nobody can see the score not even us mods.  But, disregard that part of my comment, it's irrelevant now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the Help Center information.

Firstly, 18.04 is offtopic as it is in development and not yet 'stable'. That's the first and foremost issue with the question you've linked.

We are **also** not a bug reporting site.  Yes, we're here for developers' questions - more specifically, questions about *developing* on Ubuntu.  But that doesn't extend to the reporting of **actual bugs** as questions, as those belong in bug reports, not Ask Ubuntu Q/A (especially since not all packages' developers actually pay attention here, and as Ask Ubuntu is not a discussion forum it's hard to add all the required developer troubleshooting information and such to a post, especially with the character limits on posts themselves).

***Bug reports belong as their own bugs filed on Launchpad, and not as Ask Ubuntu question/answer posts.***  The post you linked to fits into this category as well.

If you don't like how this site operates with this policy, you're free to *propose* that the policy be changed here on meta in its own specific proposal thread, and the community-at-large is able to vote on that policy.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have misinterpreted the Help Center advice.

Questions about developing software for Ubuntu are on-topic. That's what it means by "Ubuntu developers".

Questions asking developers to fix bugs are most likely off-topic, or need to be rephrased to not sound like bug reports, because bug reports are off-topic.

The question you linked to is about a pre-release version of Ubuntu. Questions about problems with alpha and beta versions are off topic because

- The developers (that's folks on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/), not us, although some of them might happen to be here...) need to see the bug reports so they can fix the bugs.
- Bugs are expected in development versions. The site would be full of such questions with minimal future usefulness.
- Questions and answers will soon be obsolete as the bugs will get fixed by the time of release (as long as they get reported on Launchpad instead of on Ask Ubuntu!).